# Why is struct array init not working when using "new" in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm learning C++ and I've encountered an interesting behavior.

Let's say I've got a struct Point with `int x` and `int y`.

I want to create an array of Points using "tagged structure initialization" syntax. This method works, the result is 3:

```
Point p[3] { {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6} };
cout << p[1].x;
```

But if I want to create these with the `new` keyword, it does not work. I don't get any compiler errors, nor runtime errors, but the fields remain uninitialized:

```
Point *p = new Point[3] { {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6} };
cout << p[1].x; // some random number from memory
```

Regular constructors work this way, but this doesn't. I understand that this is NOT a constructor, just a simplified syntax to assign values to the fields at once, but I'm curious why the first solution works, and the second one not.

Thank You for helping me!

Comment: this works fine [here](http://cpp.sh/7wfh). Which version of which compiler do you use?

Comment: It works well http://ideone.com/RwpqWA

Comment: @chris Thanks for pointing that out. I clearly misread the question.

Comment: I think it has something to do with [aggregate-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) but I haven't find why it wouldn't work in your case.

Comment: Try adding a Point(int x, int y) constructor.

Comment: I used Visual Studio 2015 and its compiler, and it turned out that was the problem. I tried compiling it with GCC, and it worked as expected.